# How to write JEST unit test case for code for stateless function in REACT JS shown below:

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, testcase

I have a function in a stateless component for which branch coverage should be written.  Example snippet:
In coverage file, it shows I as shown in code below near if statement.  How to pass this statements.

```js
const somefuncxxx= ({
  x,
  y
}) => {
    const somefunc = () => {
      if(x && y){
        return <div className="xxxx">xyz</div>
      } else if(x){
        return <div className=xxx">x</div>
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code, where is `x`, `y` variables? Clarify your question

Comment: Looks like x and y might be in closure scope. In that case you won't be able to cover all the if else conditions without the enclosing component

Comment: @NithinThampi I have updated the question.  My query is how to check if statement in jest unit test case.  suppose if(x) is true test should be pass or fail.